# Multicollinearity and fixed effects

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, multicollinearity

I am dealing with some collinearity issues with a fixed effect negative binomial model. I am currently working with **fixest** package in R.

In few words, many of my regressors are collinear with the county and time fixed effects

I want to predict a model with homicide as the outcome variable. I have a panel dataset of n=2500 counties measured across 14 years. I am also incorporating county and year fixed effects.

Below is the code I am working with:

```r
f2 <- fenegbin(homicide ~ treatmentdummy +
 log(gdppc) +
 gasprice +
 offset(log(pobconapo))
| id + year,
               se= "standard",
            panel.id = ~id+year,
            data=panel)
```

I am experiencing two type of collinearity problems. First, variable **gasprice** is collinear with fixed effect **year**. In my dataset, gasprice is the national average price of gas during that year. Gasprice is thus equal to every county in the year,
At the same time, **gdppc** is collinear with fixed effect **county**.
I understand the reason that these variables are collinear. My question is, what am I doing wrong. I've seen dozens of panel set regressions with time invariant variables. Is there any way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Welcome. Why do you think you’re doing something wrong?

Comment: Random-effects type approaches (my answer here outlines what I interpret as such an approach, the terminology is somewhat crowded: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode/188559#188559) can handle time-invariant variables. Not sure about specifics for the negative binomial though